# Trying to get timer to start once arrived on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made the following fiddle of what I have right now..

https://jsfiddle.net/r5yj99bs/1/

I'm trying to start right when I get onto a page, but allowing the option to leave the pause/resume option. Then is there anyway to display the remaining time as '5 minutes' instead of '300 seconds' and then count down that way rather than only seconds.

```
<button class="start-pause">Start</button>
<h2 class="time-left"></h2>

var times = [];
var counter_interval;
var $time_left = $('.time-left');
var $button = $('.start-pause');

// timer length in seconds
var timer_length = 300;

$('body').on('click', '.start-pause', function() {

    // are we starting or stopping?
    var starting = times.length % 2 == 0;

    times.push(Date.now());

    if (starting) {
        $button.html('Pause');
        counter_interval = setInterval(function() {


            var time_left = Math.floor(timer_length - sum_elapsed());

            if (time_left < 1) {
                clearInterval(counter_interval);
                return finished();
            }

            $time_left.html(time_left);

        }, 100);
    } else {
        $button.html('Resume');
        clearInterval(counter_interval);
    }
});

var sum_elapsed = function() {
    sum = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<times.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            sum += (times[i] - times[i-1]);
        }

        if (i == (times.length - 1)) {
            sum += (Date.now() - times[i]);
        }
    }
    // convert milliseconds to seconds
    return sum / 1000;
};

var finished = function() {
    $button.attr('disabled','disabled').html('Finished');
    $time_left.html("Time's Up");
};
```

Comment: *"Then is there anyway I can turn 300 seconds into 5 minutes?"* ... ... wat

Comment: What??? 300 seconds is five minutes. Is there any way I can show 5 minutes and then 4 minutes with a second count with it. Like 4 minutes 30 seconds. Rather than it count down from 300 seconds. I don't why you don't understand that.

Comment: I think the same... What?? Or best WTF? You didn't study maths? `300 / 60 = 5`?

Comment: I understand the same, so maybe you are writing wrong your question

Comment: "turn 300 seconds into 5 minutes" is *very different* from "display remaining time as '5 minutes' instead of '300 seconds'".

Comment: Things don't need to be so technical on here. I'm displaying 300 seconds and show so in my fiddle, so saying turn 300 seconds into 5 minutes isn't so difficult to visualize. I admin I could have written it better though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good time module called moment. You can get it through npm or from moments.com

That can format relative time to human readable strings.

If you want to do it yourself, take the seconds modulus 60 to get the minutes. Using modulus you can extract all info about hours and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the following line:
`$time_left.html(time_left);`

to:
`$time_left.html(secToMinTxt(time_left));`

and add the following functions:

```
function pad(num) {
    var str = "" + num;
    var pad = "00";
    return pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str;
}

function secToMinTxt(seconds) {
    var min = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var sec = seconds % 60;
    return pad(min) + ":" + pad(sec);
}
```

JSFiddle reference : https://jsfiddle.net/r5yj99bs/2/

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, try using `Math.round` with argument existing `time_left` variable divided by `60`

```
var time_left = Math.round(Math.floor(timer_length - sum_elapsed()) / 60);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r5yj99bs/3/